# What is the advantage of posting to Documentation instead of asking and answering myself?

Tags: discussion, documentation, instant-self-answer

My impression so far is that most of what Documentation proposes could be achieved with questions answered by their own authors. We are used to this pattern, the existence of a question implies the example is somewhat realistic, and requests are basically questions themselves. Why would I post to documentation instead of forming and answering a question?

Comment: It's already difficult enough getting questions closed for certain tags! I wouldn't want to see an influx of Doc-style Q/A examples flood the main site, as I'd expect the SO review queues would explode based on the volume of new flags/votes for VLQ, dupe, etc.

Comment: I think one reason would be that it isolates Documentation reviews from SO (Q/A) reviews, keeping each more manageable.

Comment: @PetahChristian You can *already* self-answer questions on SO, it's [explicitly encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), and yet the review queues are not clogged with crappy self-answers.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I realize that self-answering is possible. My point is that the quality of an SO self-answer appears to be higher than the bar set for Doc topics (and people are already familiar with what wouldn't cut it on SO). Maybe there was a mad rush to Docs for rep, and people just threw stuff on Docs, but what manages to get approved there probably wouldn't fly here.

Comment: @PetahChristian "what manages to get approved there probably wouldn't fly here." Exactly! All the more reason to write canonical Q&A instead of posting to Docs. (I can see other reasons to use Docs instead of self-answering, but the review queue isn't one of them.)

Comment: If you self-answer "How do I initialize arrays in Java?", you'll get a flood of downvotes.  If you edit someone else's Docs topic on "How to initialize arrays in Java", you get a flood of upvotes, even if someone edits your change out later.  Choose where to post accordingly.  (Besides quality standards, random 1-rep users can also edit or delete your Docs contributions.)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I like your example because it took me to the first decent Docs I have read: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays By comparing to a related question — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-java — Docs make more sense to me now.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom It seems your comment can be an answer.

Comment: That [Creating and Initializing Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays#t=201607301034175766633) is a poor example, being a collection of examples instead of several succinct examples. Hopefully there will be some length limit in the future.

Comment: This is the question I've been asking myself since the launch of Documentation beta.

Comment: I personally don't see too much point for Stack documentation.  If I want an official explanation on a MySQL function I will check Oracle's docs.  If I want a good example on how to _use_ that function, I will check Stack Overflow.  I suppose there is a middle ground, but how big is it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen True. My biggest problem with the documentation is that even users who think they understand an API often fail to grasp some subtleties which are however very well described in the official documentation.

Comment: The SO devs seem to think that a massive problem with official documentation is that it doesn't include enough copy-and-paste ready sample code. I don't know where they are getting that impression. *Most* docs I look at do indeed have usage examples, in addition to the normal API documentation. But aside from the redundancy, I question whether this is a real problem that needs solving. Examples must often be too simplified to confer true understanding. Do we really need more programmers writing code that uses APIs for which they can't be arsed to read and understand the official docs?

Answer (score 9):

I've been browsing docs and I'm already seeing that there are a couple of topics that are filling in the gaps of less than perfect official documentation.

Also I've seen cases where a topic is already well documented but gets a very comprehensive set of examples that covers a lot of subleties, but where we can see real life examples with real life values.

For example Android intents are a topic that is generally well understood, but can be used in so many different ways. It's nice having already 22 examples to cover the most popular of them in a single place. This makes the documentation pages a nice and tidy place to go for if you want to see all variations on how to use intents, allowing you to realize all the potential they have and how important they are, even if you're only getting started to know about them. And still not being overwhelmed by the huge official documentation page that contains a lot of nitty gritty that most people are not interested in.

It also allows a single place for good practices accepted by the community, instead of relying on what the vendor though was the right thing when they first wrote documentation. How many vendors review and update their documentation even without introducing feature changes? As such SO documentation has the possibility of being alive and dynamic, which is something Q&A can't be.

It can be even more interesting if we start seeing comprehensive lists popular pitfalls and errors grouped by topics, for those cases where we think that we're having a quick fix for a symptom but in fact the problem is that we really skipped understanding something fundamental to our problem.

In a way this may be a shift from an expert community writing to an expert community, towards something that may be more easily consumed by people still going up the learning curve.

Answer (score 8):

<sub>Reposting my [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333554/what-does-documentation-have-that-stack-overflow-qa-doesnt) as an answer here:</sub>

All the examples I've seen on docs could just as well have been on SO, either as a straight up answer to a question or as a canonical answer on a common subject. From what I can tell, both of those seems to work much better at producing high quality documentation.

I think the standard SO Q&A format would fit perfectly (or at least much better) for documentation. We could use a format similar to the current canonical questions to create a wiki.

### Advantages (with Q&A instead of Docs.SO)

#### Answers can compete on being the best documentation for a feature

As it stands currently, the documentation on different (but similar) topics compete with each other, which doesn't make much sense. And it's mostly first-come-first-serve that determines what example will be used for a subject.

#### We get a place for discussion for free (as comments)

Currently there is no good forum for discussing the documentation. All we have is improvement requests, which we can't respond to, SO meta, which is just loosely connected to the actual piece of documentation and the chat, which is only loosely connected and is volatile. (Shog has [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331745/make-examples-look-more-like-questions-in-qa#comment379917_331752) that some improvement is planned.)

#### The documentation requests are editable as well

Since the documentation requests will be in the form of questions, those are just as changeable as the pieces of documentation.

### Downsides

#### Lack of overview

We won't get as good overview over a subject as on the current docs.
This can be partially mitigated by having overview questions (that links to many subjects) and linking between the questions, but the related subjects will still be at least a link away.

#### Redundant questions

If most questions are on the format "What is feature X and how do I use it", the question doesn't serve much of a purpose. It might as well be replaced by just a headline.

#### Visibility

It's easy to see all the subjects on a topic in the current documentation. If we were using the standard Q&A format, most of the structure will be lost.

One possible solution is to make a summary page for each subject that contains all the top rated answers for the sub-subjects, and show the normal Q&A view with the other answers on the subject when you click on it. Or just make overview subjects like I mentioned above.

#### It's hard to change the scope of a topic

If we decide to merge two topics, split a topic or shift it slightly sideways, what should we do to the current answers to it?

And who decides what should be the scope? First come first serve is probably a bad idea.

## Summary

As it looks right now, documentation is doing worse at it's purpose than canonical questions on SO. We could probably replace it with a site consisting of just "canonical questions" and get a much better result.

Answer (score 6):

One could easily ask the question the other way around: Why would you answer yourself when you could instead contribute to Documentation?

Both is possible, so ultimately it's up to you. There are advantages and disadvantages and with future improvement of Documentation the trade-off may change.

What matters in your decision:

- Documentation is currently less established than self-answered Q&A
- Self-answered Q&A is less collaborative than Documentation (unless it's community wiki but probably even then)
- Documentation does only require a topic title, self-answered Q&A requires a full question which means more details
- Documentation can be somewhat broader than questions
- Your self-answered question and answer (unless it's community wiki) is still yours, you decide what it's about
- Your Documentation contribution may be changed to anything by anyone
- Your self-answered question is categorized by up to 5 tags and a question title
- Your Documentation contribution is categorized by one tag and one topic title
- Self-answered questions do not have to include examples in the answers, Documentation is example centered
- Visitors browsing the site or coming from search engines might find self-answered questions better than Documentation contributions or maybe the other way around (one would need to test this by contributing two times the same content and compare page impressions)

All in all, I currently don't see a decisive advantage of preferring Documentation over self-answered questions but I can imagine that after Documentation improves it could be a nice alternative to community-wiki self-answered questions that were answered by examples.

Comment: *Your self-answered question and answer is still yours* That's not true *legally*. Maybe *practically* it is, because answers aren't supposed to be revised beyond recognition. Anyway, I was starting to answer something along these lines. I agree with all points you make.

Comment: @GertArnold You're right. I meant it in the way that for Q&A we typically respect the opinion of an answerer or asker about his posts a lot and rather up/down vote while on Documentation this is explicitly not the case.

Answer (score 4):

To my mind, posting to Documentation means making your post easily accessible by people: a user enters Documentation, goes to some tag, and many posts are presented to them, so they don't need to search through the whole lot of SO questions and answers.

What's more, Documentation's organized by topics, which may consist of different posts discussing some aspects of a particular topic. And all of them are already here, sorted and polished *by many users*, while the questions and answers one can find on SO are normally written and edited by only one person (others suggest minor edits, but the *main contents* is written by OP).

The point is, there are tons of questions & answers on SO, and your post may get lost easily (if it's not really outstanding<sup>1</sup>) as many people come here only to *get their problems solved*<sup>2</sup>, not to generalize and/or *monitor* and *improve* their posts as new aspects or solutions arise (and this is what people do - or at least *are supposed to do* - on Documentation).

---

<sub>1. also see the comments</sub>

<sub>2. as I've said in the comments, Documentation's about *how to use some technology*, not about giving advice about what to do if you've already *shot yourself in the foot* with this technology</sub>

Comment: *"...and your post may get lost easily"* If only someone would invent a way to solve that problem. Oh wait, they did! Many years before Stack Overflow was even invented. It's called search, and Google has brought a version of it to the web that demonstrates almost complete mastery of the domain. So yeah, not being able to find the information is indeed a problem, but it is a solved problem. And even if it were not, creating a second place to duplicate the information (and yet another place for it to get buried among heaps of "topics" and "examples") would not be a valid solution.

Comment: @CodyGray, if you use search, only _popular_ information is shown, sometimes it's even absolutely not what you want. So, if your post doesn't get _noticed_ (and upvoted, linked to on other web sites, etc), it it will _get lost_ despite the existence of Google. To get noticed among loads of SO posts, one'll have to try very hard and will need some luck as well. To get noticed on Documentation, just write a post, and it will drive much more attention to itself as there are not so many posts, I suppose.

Comment: That has not been my experience at all. When I search for answers to my problems, I find lots of Stack Overflow questions and answers that have low scores. (Naturally, if I find them to be helpful, I try to rectify that situation, but I can only cast one vote.) I mean, yeah, what you're describing is Google's PageRank algorithm, where things that are popular tend to get more juice and therefore appear higher on the search results. But that is generally what you want. If there's a more helpful answer, you want it to be at the top. If there isn't, you'll see less popular stuff.

Comment: And I don't really know why you make the assumption that Documentation will solve this problem. Popular Q&A get upvoted, and so will popular Documentation. What is unique about Documentation that will cause unpopular content to get noticed and upvoted when it wouldn't have been if it were posted as a Q&A? This is working now because Documentation is new and very small. Q&A worked that way, too, when it was new and small. But it won't be long, given the rate at which people are contributing new examples and topics for the easy rep gain, that Docs will be full to the gill and unwieldy, too.

Comment: @CodyGray, perhaps because Documentation is a new and popular feature, and many people became interested in filling it with useful content and improving other people's  writings. Then, nowadays there are certainly much less posts on Documentation, so a new one will attract more attention than it would on SO. Also, maybe this wasn't clear enough, I'm talking about _new_, not _unpopular_, content here.

Comment: @CodyGray, I didn't see your edit, and so wrote about almost the same thing you're talking about now. I think that Documentation's supposed to be much smaller than SO as all the technology people are discussing there is not as big and rich as _the amount of problems_ people have with this technology. But Documentation's not about solving problems, it's about writing the docs (about _how to use_ this stuff, not what to do after someone's shot himself in the foot with it).

Answer (score 3):

*Collaboration* is the answer and main difference from self-answering (As I see it) - The documentation allows you to improve my answer, and I can improve yours - And we'll both (unfortunately) be credited with +5 rep on future upvotes, even if I only changed your example from `alert('hello world');` into `alert('hello world!');`.

Comment: This assumes that the answer is not marked as a community wiki or that the edits are not made by a 2k+ user

Comment: Yes. What I meant is that the Documentation project is Collaboration oriented - There's no "mine" or "yours" - Anyone can contribute by creating examples, edit existing, approve/reject changes proposal. This what's make a post in the documentation different from self-answering