# Make Examples look more like questions in Q&A

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation, user-interface

When I discovered Stack Overflow, I remember that the interface was immediately intuitive to me. Title goes here, question goes there, add tags, done. Add a comment, cool. Share the link, easy. Vote to close, done.

This is not my experience with Documentation. Whenever I follow someone's link to a Documentation Example, I get *super* confused.

- The table of contents and the content being almost the same width in the split screen view is confusing

  [image]

  (This is not as egregious in the single-column view - but most of the other problems remain.)
- It is awfully easy to accidentally scroll away from the section I wanted to read/jump to (because there is content above and below, just *touching* the scroll wheel makes you lose it)
- I still need 30 secs each time to figure out what I need to do e.g. when I want to suggest a new edit to something
- I still need to hover over each icon each time to figure out what they mean
- Having the examples be part of a list that you can scroll up and down (and jump to dynamically) doesn't seem to serve any purpose currently, as the order of examples is random.

This doesn't feel like an ideal experience, neither as a consumer (imagine someone ending up directly at an example through Google), nor as an editor/reviewer. It also doesn't feel like a part of SO.

Could this whole thing not be made much more to resemble the traditional Q&A interface - splitting each example into an artifact of its own?

To oversimplify:

[image]

I realize the Documentation team must have spent a *lot* of time  on how to approach Documentation's UI... there are probably good reasons why everything looks like it does that I just don't see.

But I really have problems using the UI as it is, and the fancy JS feels counterproductive to the experience.

Comment: Have you seen the split-screen view? http://i.stack.imgur.com/IGf56.png

Comment: @Shog that is exactly the view I'm complaining about :) Only just saw how it behaves with less available width. Neither is superior to having each Example as a separate artifact (IMO)

Comment: @Shog I added a professional infographic to clarify things

Comment: You can turn off the split view by clicking the 'x' in between the two columns. The default is the single-column view.

Comment: @Kurtis Yeah, I only discovered it after Shog's comment, not sure how I could overlook that! I *think* I got the split-screen by default (I can't remember having consciously chosen it). Maybe it was a private Beta thing. Anyway - the single-screen view is much better. If that's what the average joe gets to see that seems much less of a problem then. But the fundamental suggestion (making each Example a separate artifact on its own page, and streamlining the UI with Q&A as much as possible) still stands

Comment: There are some things in here that we were already considering in a future iteration. Thanks for your feedback. The idea of a ToC in the sidebar is something we were already considering. Not certain about the dividing examples into their own artifact — the idea has merit and advantages. It's a bit of a departure from the original concept so we'd need to think through all the implications carefully.

Comment: I accidentally triggered the split-screen view almost *immediately* after first looking at Documentation. I have no idea how I did it. I remember it was very jarring, I didn't like it, and I couldn't figure out how to make it go away. The whole experience was very negative, and left a bad taste in my mouth. I'm very glad you posted this; the entire UI is an over-complex disaster that looks like it was never actually tested. hairboat assures me this isn't true and the UX team isn't full of bozos obsessed with throbbing blue circles, but I'm still dubious how this one ever got out the door.

Answer (score 17):

I like the idea of **a light-weight outline/ToC in the sidebar**. You actually get this when *editing*, to help you keep track of what's been changed:

[image: Topic Outline for LINQ Queries topic]

Having this in the sidebar of the page could actually free up some room in the editor, which would be nice.

The **action icons** I feel less strongly about; after 8 years, I'm *used to* the text links on Q&A, but plenty of folks still get confused by them. Terms like "share" and "flag" don't always mean the same thing (and in fact we've changed the names or meanings on Q&A at various points) - heck, [even "comment" is potentially misleading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256967/change-comment-to-critique-or-request-clarification). So while I find the iconography annoying right now, I have to admit that it consumes less space... And may not be any more confusing to new users than the text actions on Q&A.

As far as ***adding* comments to examples**... I think this would make the page even more cluttered. The primary mode of interaction with Docs is intended to be *editing*; if folks start dumping suggestions or errata into comments, that falls apart. I do suspect we're going to need some sort of a "talk" page for these topics eventually though, something that aggregates improvement requests and associated discussion so we can resolve disagreements over goals and edits for a topic without getting into edit wars.

Comment: The problems with improvement requests are that they're too short and allow no room for discussion. Without the latter, there's no way to build consensus for a change. And without that, you basically invite edit warring. You guys *really* need to examine the Wikipedia model of collaborative editing; they've got a decade's worth of experience on how to build a useful knowledgebase of information. And right now, you seem to be doing many things exactly opposite of how they handle things.

Comment: That's why I said, I think we're gonna need some equivalent to WP's "talk" pages. Right now, those improvement requests essentially drop out of sight, and any discussion is either attached to the associated improvements, lost in chat, or non-existent. That's going to become an issue as we move beyond the "tent city" stage.

Comment: While you're right that words don't always have unambiguous meanings, inscrutable little icons have even *less* obvious meanings, so I'm not really sure what the argument is here. I literally have to use the tooltips every time to see what the icons mean. It doesn't help that the options change depending on which view you're in, so memorization and muscle memory become less useful. And if it's true that you want to drive people to editing, burying it in a tiny icon (that is similar to a pencil, but has a strange line coming out of it) isn't really a smart way of doing it.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm really happy to hear that you're talking about discussion pages. Adding that early on will help avoid some cultural problems (edit wars). It'll be a welcome addition I think.