# Don't auto-expand the first three examples when navigating to a topic

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation, design, documentation-topics

When I enter a topic for the first time, without having followed a link to a specific example, I end up on a page with the first three examples already expanded. For instance, opening [Promises on JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises#t=201608092048291468621) opens looking something like this:

> [image: Opening expanded]

So, I've read the intro example before... I just want to get an overview of what kinds of examples this topic has.

Maybe if I click on the double-chevron thingy in the upper right?

> [image: Expand all the things!]

Okay... not much difference. Oh wait, the chevrons point up now! Neat! And my scrollbar grabbie thing got a lot smaller. So I guess that expanded everything.

Fine, I'll bite. What happens when I click on the double-chevron thing again?

> [image: w00t!]

There it is! That's what I wanted to see. Why was that so exhausting?

It seems to me, if the default behavior is to have examples expanded, the default behavior of the the "expand/collapse all" button should be to collapse all examples. I do realize it's only three which are expanded, but those are all I see "above the fold".

---

Note that when you go to a specific example, it also expands those first three by default, along with expanding the one you want to see. This is very odd behavior in my book, but since you get scrolled up to the example you want, it's less noticeable.

Comment: Having the top three expanded by default also makes it a lot harder to even realize that there are other examples to skim through.  A lot of examples are so big that they push the list beyond the height of the window.  The default behavior should be "here's examples by name (still sorted by votes), click the one that you're interested in".

Comment: A more radical alternative: only show one example at a time, let the rest be listed in a (floating?) sidebar TOC http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331745

Comment: Would auto-expanding the pinned examples be a good compromise?

Comment: If you want that, you can click the button directly to the left of the chevrons.

Comment: We're considering some updates to the UI to address these issues that may or may not include a TOC and could possibly eliminate the expanding and collapsing of examples. You can expect an update from the team soon

Comment: I would also prefer it if they were all collapsed by default. Or perhaps do it wiki style, with a content table at the top and the examples below. But I think there are a lot more possibilities to improve the UI. Right now I sometimes don't even see where one example ends and where the other starts.

Comment: Documents has so many issues it needs its own meta before it's even out of beta

Comment: I think this is part of the reason I'm having trouble getting a grip on Documentation. I get presented with a lot of information before I even understand what I am looking at.

Answer (score 16):

I think that ideally examples should have a 3-5 lines state in which they can be put. Sort of in between expanded and collapsed, but forced to be very brief. No definitions, they would be in the full example.

Just an abstract. A teaser for the example. Maybe a snippet of code would be nice.

That way, you can have the best of both worlds: oversight of the examples, but also actually see what the topic looks like at first glance (e.g. syntax, etc.)

Here's a thousand words, with a snippet just for the 3 first examples, from the topic you linked:

[image: small examples]

<sub>I know the "Click for more" are ugly and not in SO style, but someone with better skills than me at UIs needs to think about how to convey that the snippet isn't the full example. This will do for this preview.</sub>

Comment: I like the idea, and would extend it by having, as @Greg mentions below, a "three-state chevron", allowing one to put all of the examples into either: a) All collapsed, b) All fully expanded, or c) All excerpts. I don't know that having a different initial state buys us much of anything.

Answer (score 3):

Requiring two clicks to collapse was just a bug. It's fixed as of a few days ago.

Answer (score 2):

I **agree** that the chevron state changes are a bit confusing, and last week I almost filed a bug thinking it wasn't working correctly on the first click. But then I realized it 1) started in partial expanded mode, 2) switched to full expansion on the first click, and 3) toggled between full expanded/collapsed on subsequent clicks.

I **disagree** that all examples should start collapsed though, as it is nice to have the actual content visible when you enter a topic. Also if you link to a specific example it is less of an issue (and that is expected to be a common entry point eventually as docs get used in Q&A and else where), since that example is then expanded and scrolled into view when you load the page.

I do think that having a 3 state chevron icon instead of 2 state icon would help eliminate some of the confusion. Maybe just adding a + or something under the arrows when transitioning from the initial state to full expansion.

Alternatively the first click could collapse all examples instead of expand all, but I kind of like the current progression (some content, all content, minimal content).

Answer (score 0):

As a new user landing on Documentation, I'm not at all sure that the chevrons are at all intuitive in the first place. Sure there is a tooltip, but that presumes I'm waving the mouse around looking for things to press. Mostly people hit websites for information, not to spend ten minutes figuring out the interface. Meaning they're far more likely to simply start scrolling down, than looking for widgets.

A Collapse / Expand Examples button would be immediately obvious and intuitive as to what it did.