# How are readers linked to an Example supposed to navigate to the Remarks?

Tags: discussion, documentation

In [What's Documentation for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343678/whats-documentation-for) the OP noted that

> [the Example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/1319/asyncio-module/4310/asynchronous-executors#t=201702142143594337196) [in Topic "Asyncio Module"] uses concepts like "asyncio" and "executors" without explanation even though this is my first time encountering them

It makes perfect sense that the Example shouldn't explain what asyncio is, though, right? The Topic is asyncio, so the concept should not be re-explained in each Example, but rather explained a single time [in the Remarks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-anatomy) or Intro.

Ok, but how is the reader landing from Google search (or even from SO) supposed to know that? Remarks at the bottom are not really fit for purpose since hardly anyone who needs to read them will know they're there. Besides, now that Examples are not foldable, scrolling to the bottom and back can be a hassle.

I'm thinking [a better layout](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331745/make-examples-look-more-like-questions-in-qa) could present Intro, a single Example and Remarks a lot closer to each other (along with other optional sections: Syntax and Parameters). But I don't really know if that's the best solution, which is why I marked this as a discussion.

---

Similarly, no one will naturally navigate to the Introduction at the top when coming from SO Docs search (which jumps the user down to the Example). As far as I can tell, Google only links to Topics, not Examples, so presumably those visitors would always see the Introduction section at the top.