# Are "trouble-shooting" topics (or examples) worthwhile in Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation

*You've experienced it ...*

... another beginning coder has re-asked the same question that has been asked many times before.

... and you routinely point these duplicate questions to canonical original answers.

In most S.O. Tags there is a small set of questions that are repeatedly asked  by beginning coders. These are the common mistakes and misunderstandings that beginning coders inevitably make while learning.

**Is "Troubleshooting X" a good Topic (or Example) on Documentation?**

Q&A clearly covers the needs of beginning coders when it comes to their beginning mistakes & misunderstandings ...

But ...

A "Troubleshooting" Topic within a Tag could be a useful central location for inexperienced programmers to find answers their own answers to the most common problems that occur in the Tag.

A Troubleshooting Topic could answer common beginners problems so a Q&A might not even have to be created.

Or taking it a bit further ...

Currently, before asking a question, questioners are given a list of possible Q&A that might solve their problem. It might be useful to also show the questioner a Documentation Topic or Example that covers their question.

Should Documentation include troubleshooting?

Comment: Rather sounds like a good topic for a canonical question.

Answer (score 14):

Your question is based on a false premise: the idea that, if we provide a "useful central location" for these kinds of things, then "inexperienced programmers" will find it and refrain from asking those questions to begin with.

Sorry, but reality shows that that isn't going to work. In many cases, that information is already available if you do a simple Google search. If a user isn't willing to use the most basic information finding tool out there, then they're not going to dig through some random topic on Docs.SO.

Asking questions is *always easier* for them. And for these sorts of people, the right answer is the easiest.

However, let's pretend that we're dealing with a species of inexperienced programmer that actually does due diligence before asking questions. So the question is, will a "Troubleshooting" topic get them information faster or easier?

No.

Such a topic will be, as with much else on Docs.SO, a random grab-bag of stuff. An unsorted mass of various and sundry miscellany. Even if we ignore the limits topics have on the number of examples, it's still just a giant page of stuff. No different from the thousands of FAQ pages that *nobody reads*. Why?

Because the signal-to-noise ratio on FAQ pages is *terrible.* If you're trying to solve a problem, and the solution actually exists on such a page, then the SNR is 1:N, where N is the number of FAQs on the page. The more FAQs, the less useful the page is.

Or in the case of such topics, the number of examples in a topic. Yet another reason to prefer focused topics to groups of examples selected by some arbitrary metric. With a focused topic, a person reading that topic to find a solution to their problem will have a better SNR.

Comment: So cynical! There are those (I among them) who learn well by reading -- manuals, tutorials ... and yes, even Documentation. So I reject as overly broad your disqualifying statement that "Asking questions is *always* easier for them". There are too many "non-thems" out here. You may have a point about Troubleshooting == a grab-bag of "various", but a good Troubleshooting post would certainly not be "miscellany". Instead it would pull from the most often asked Q&A that have tripped-up beginners. It would give beginners a grab-bag of fixes to problems we know from experience they must avoid.

Comment: If you are a beginner you may learn somthing additional by perusing the FAQ, the signal to noise might actually be closer to 1:1 because everything is potentially interesting for you. However I totally agree. We should only have dedicated topics and then refer to them. A troubleshooting topic just means we haven't thought about proper topic titles yet. We don't have much categorization with Documentation and at least topics we should get right.

Comment: @markE: "*There are too many "non-thems" out here.*" No, there aren't. The kind of people who read documentation and search for answers on their own *don't ask* these kinds of duplicate questions. So clearly, my commentary was not directed towards them.

Comment: @markE: "*a good Troubleshooting post would certainly not be "miscellany"*" Miscellany: "a miscellaneous collection or group of various or somewhat unrelated items." The key point being that the different examples are *unrelated*. The only relationship between them is that they're "troubleshooting". That's not a useful relationship for being able to quickly find information. Encyclopedias don't have lists of unrelated things.

Comment: @Trilarion. Pre-question FAQ (based on a keyword search) must help a certain percentage of questioners find answers before they need to actually ask their question -- otherwise the powers-that-be would have done away with FAQ. So that same keyword search could find a relevant troubleshooting Example. Since Examples are slightly broader than Q&A, the Examples might well answer questions that Q&A misses. I agree with you that troubleshooting Topics & troubleshooting Examples should have explicit titles so the pre-questioner can choose the title that answers their question.

Comment: @markE: "*otherwise the powers-that-be would have done away with FAQ*" That's different. That's a *dynamically generated* list. It's not curated by anyone; nobody created it or put elements into it. It's simply a search list based on what you've entered thus far. A "troubleshooting topic" is *static*. It contains a random mishmash of whatever. It has no practical value as a means of organizing information.

Comment: @NicolBolas. A dictionary definition of "miscellany" -- really? Then your use of both "various" and "miscellany" seems redundant because miscellany seems to include various. I assumed you wanted to use "various" as shorthand for "a related SET of information that are common to a viewer's current needs" and "miscellany" as shorthand for "an largely unrelated, and possibly random, bag of stuff". Troubleshooting's valuable relationship is that these mistakes & misunderstandings are common to beginning coders. You might argue that this relationship is insufficient, but it IS the glue that binds.

Comment: @markE: "*You might argue that this relationship is insufficient*" It's not that it's "insufficient". It's that it isn't *helpful*. The amount of stuff that would qualify as "mistakes & misunderstandings are common to beginning coders" is ***endless***. It's a bottomless pit of stuff. If you're looking for a solution to a specific problem, you do not look in bottomless pits, sifting through them in the hope that someone, somewhere did in fact add your specific problem to an example.

Comment: @NicolBolas. Documentation can be approached by users in several ways: 1. Browsing by Topic or  2. keyword searches. So even if a topic contains "various" (see my usage above) information, the keyword search will find the relevant information. I heard words from you like "mishmash", "bag", and even "unrelated". That's not what I'm proposing! "Troubleshooting" has been a section in many documentation manuals. And yes, Troubleshooting Topics & Examples should have explicit titles for those beginners who browse by topic rather than search by keyword.

Comment: Based on the logic of the false premise that you suggest shouldn't we just throw all the documentation out entirely?

Comment: @NicolBolas. Certainly not "endless, bottomless pits" at all -- you're catastrophizing! I've reviewed over 2000 previous Q&A in my tiny [html5-Canvas] tag and can find a clear pattern. I have identified 8 "Troubleshooting X in html5 canvas" Topics and each Topic has less than 8 examples (most topics have 3-4).

Comment: @Rodger. Chuckle! Yes, I have swallowed the Kool-Aid. I contribute to Documentation and I believe that it will make a positive contribution to understanding in the long run. It currently has some rough edges that need to be smoothed, It even has some critical shortcomings that it must overcome. Aside: For all the lighthearted bantering that NicolBolas & I go through about specificity, we both want Documentation to thrive.

Comment: @markE: "*keyword searches*" At which point, the location of an example is *irrelevant*. And therefore, "troubleshooting topics" are only relevant when people are browsing by topic.

Comment: I think it is a worthwhile endeavor also, I just don't know if you can apply the "people that need it won't read it" logic selectively. ;)

Comment: @NicolBolas. Sooooooooo...you never use Google to keyword search for SO content? :-0 My point is that *both* browsing by top *and* keyword searching bring beginners to "Troubleshooting X" topics & to explicitly titled "Example of X & how to solve it". I have no facts for this claim, but keyword searches might be the most common way that users find SO content. By extension, keyword searches will lead beginners to Troubleshooting content.

Comment: @Rodger. I think you've found the basis of my question. :-) Should I bother creating Troubleshooting content, and if yes, how do I organize troubleshooting content. BTW, I ask the question because I really am undecided. I believe there is troubleshooting content that is needed by beginners and I'm unclear how to present it.

Answer (score 1):

Summary: Use specific titles and only if the topic can be explained in examples.

Q&A has canonical questions for dealing with common problems/misunderstandings which act as duplicate targets (which doesn't prevent asking the questions but at least minimizes the effort of answering them).

Documentation topics are example-centric, so the content would need to be explainable with examples.

If this is the case the Documentation topics should be named analogously to the canonical Q&As: use specific and focused topics titles to treat common misunderstandings one by one.

Example:

- Tag Java: "Detect and fix NullPointerExceptions"

Comment: What would a Documentation topic on detecting and fixing NullPointerExceptions offer over [the canonical Q&A we already have on detecting and fixing NullPointerExceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)?

Comment: @CodyGray Better structure maybe? The canonical Q&A maybe has some redundancy because of having the list of answers which Documentation doesn't have. I don't see a big advantage there, it may be a matter of taste and Documentation has at least the focus on examples which also limits it. See also: [What is the advantage of posting to Documentation instead of asking and answering myself?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330129/what-is-the-advantage-of-posting-to-documentation-instead-of-asking-and-answerin).