# What does documentation have that Stack Overflow Q&A doesn't?

Tags: discussion, documentation

All the examples I've seen on docs could just as well have been on SO, either as a straight up answer to a question or as a canonical answer on a common subject. From what I can tell, both of those seems to work much better at producing high quality documentation.

I think the standard SO Q&A format would fit perfectly (or at least much better) for documentation. We could use a format similar to the current canonical questions to create a wiki.

### Advantages (with Q&A instead of Docs.SO)

#### Answers can compete on being the best documentation for a feature

As it stands currently, the documentation on different (but similar) topics compete with each other, which doesn't make much sense. And it's mostly first-come-first-serve that determines what example will be used for a subject.

#### We get a place for discussion for free (as comments)

Currently there is no good forum for discussing the documentation. All we have is improvement requests, which we can't respond to, SO meta, which is just loosely connected to the actual piece of documentation and the chat, which is only loosely connected and is volatile. (Shog has [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331745/make-examples-look-more-like-questions-in-qa#comment379917_331752) that some improvement is planned.)

#### The documentation requests are editable as well

Since the documentation requests will be in the form of questions, those are just as changeable as the pieces of documentation.

### Downsides

#### Lack of overview

We won't get as good overview over a subject as on the current docs.
This can be partially mitigated by having overview questions (that links to many subjects) and linking between the questions, but the related subjects will still be at least a link away.

#### Redundant questions

If most questions are on the format "What is feature X and how do I use it", the question doesn't serve much of a purpose. It might as well be replaced by just a headline.

#### Visibility

It's easy to see all the subjects on a topic in the current documentation. If we were using the standard Q&A format, most of the structure will be lost.

One possible solution is to make a summary page for each subject that contains all the top rated answers for the sub-subjects, and show the normal Q&A view with the other answers on the subject when you click on it. Or just make overview subjects like I mentioned above.

#### It's hard to change the scope of a topic

If we decide to merge two topics, split a topic or shift it slightly sideways, what should we do to the current answers to it?

And who decides what should be the scope? First come first serve is probably a bad idea.

## Summary

As it looks right now, documentation is doing worse at it's purpose than canonical questions on SO. We could probably replace it with a site consisting of just "canonical questions" and get a much better result.

Comment: "As it looks right now" is probably the operative point here. Being in public beta, it's open for suggestions and improvements.

Comment: This question would actually be a good answer to the question linked in my last comment.

Comment: @LukeMoll I agree, but my idea of improvement, which is in the line of "scrap the whole project and replace it with a new SE-site", is probably not going to get much traction. ;)

Comment: @Hjulle quite possibly not, but itemising the pros and cons as you've done, there's a clear way that the devs and mods can distinguish Docs from QA. They both have purposes, but different ones. And I agree given that Docs aims to cover a broader knowledge base per topic, discussion Wiki talk-style would be needed even more than QA, but as you said it's hopefully in the pipes anyway

Comment: All good and valid points.